# Backbone.js cancel Model.destroy

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

When I call Model.destroy, it sends the proper requests to the server. However, I handle errors not so `RESTful`, I return a JSON with some appropriate information instead of throwing a http exception.

Now I want to be able to prevent the deletion of the model in the callbacks. For ex;

```
window.UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //Other stuff here.
    clearSuccess: function (model, response) {
        if (!response.Exception) {
            $(this.el).fadeOut('fast', function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }
        else {
            //Can I cancel the destroy here?
        }
    },
    clearFailed: function (model, response) {
        alert("failed");
    }
});
```

These are the 2 callbacks that I sent to the model's `success` and `error` parameter on the `destroy` method. So where my comment is, I'd like to tell Backbone.js "nevermind, server said I cant delete, so keep the model". How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have control of the content body with ASP.net MVC. Just set the Response.StatusCode property to the value you want to use, then return a JSON response or a Content response, or whatever.

```
Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Conflict;
return Json( errorMessage );
```

Works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing is probably to return both a non-success HTTP status code (400-599) and a response body with a JSON document with application-level error details.  See this thread for more on the HTTP status:

[Using HTTP status codes to reflect success/failure of Web service request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496193/using-http-status-codes-to-reflect-success-failure-of-web-service-request)

If you do this, backbone should automatically know that a failure status means the destroy did not succeed on the server, and I think it will do the right thing.

Comment: The thing about that is I'm using asp.net mvc, I have no control of the content body I return :(. This guy tried to help me, so I turned to json content; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639931/asp-net-mvc-httpexception-message-not-shown-on-client/6640082#6640082