# HTTP Web Service and HTTP Response codes

Tags: .net, web-services, http

I'm writing a Plain Old XML HTTP request/response service and am looking for advice as to how to respond to the caller.

Given that the response is XML, would you advise:

1. Return HTTP Status 200 all the time, and embed the response success/failure inside the XML, using a kind of "return code" approach? e.g. `<myResponse><returnCode></returnCode><myPayload/></myResponse>`
2. Use the HTTP Status Codes to indicate success or failure.

This may be similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496193/using-http-status-codes-to-reflect-success-failure-of-web-service-request).

Comment: Being a big fan of RESTful services, I'd advocate that you always use the applicable response code and add the details in the response content.  Is there a particular reason not to use the codes?

Comment: No, there is no specific reason I can think of other than general ignorance and my own tradition/ experience of consuming other similar services

Comment: In that case I'd definitely recommend using the applicable response codes until such a reason becomes an issue (such as a connecting client that handles codes incorrectly).  It's a pet peeve of mine when I connect to a service that breaks HTTP standards.  I once had to integrate with a service that would indicate a "404" by sending a redirect and then returning a 200 where the page content just _said_ 404 in it.  So basically the service said, "That resource has moved here... This resource is the correct one.  But it's still not found."  Made no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google and Amazon services use returning 200 only if your request was valid AND the response is valid.

For example using Google Contact API

- If you request a Contact that exists: 200 + XML/Json of Contact
- If you request a Contact that does not exists: 404 + Xml/Json with Details
- If your request is formatted improperly: 400 + Xml/Json with Details
- If you have not sent the authorization token: 401 + Xml/Json with Details
- If you attempt to Insert a contact using Get or Put: 405
- If you Attempt to Insert a Contact using Post: 200 (assuming the request contant was valid)
- If you Attempt to Update a Contact using Get or Post: 405
- If you attempt to Update a Contact using Put: 200 (assuming the request contant was valid)
- If you Attempt to Delete a Contact using Get, Put, Post: 405
- If you attempt to Delete a contact using Delete: 200 (assuming the request contant was valid)

I would highly recommend you do NOT always return a 200.  The HTTP Status codes are designed around a response code result that represents the request.  As shown above, if you request is not correct, then using HTTP Status codes is a valid solution.

I would recommend using a 5XX if there is a problem on your end.  I really wish Google would do this.  (At one point their Experimental OAuth 2.0 endpoint was not working, and instead of throwing a 503 - Service Unavailable, I was getting a 400 - Bad Request, which made me thing I was doing something wrong....)

For descriptions of the HTTP Status Codes check out [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

Comment: If I'm not suggesting that the service is RESTful, or REST-compliant, what would the HTTP response codes give me over my own application-level response structure?

Comment: You would be using it as it was intended to be used.  I personally would rather see an HTTP response.  My preference is based on using other large corporations who also do the same thing.

Comment: Upvoted because many people who write webservices should keep it in mind for future reference...

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you'd want to go with option 1 because your request could be successful but something fails on the backend in your api. I wouldn't return a response code of 200 all the time though, you could run into a case where say the url for the web service doesn't exist, in that case you'd want to return the appropriate response code.

Comment: Using your example, wouldn't a non-existent URL 404 response be handled by the web server?